# Keyboard shortcut to switch to bottom pane (command prompt) in gedit

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys, gedit

I'm on Ubuntu, and using `gedit` for some minor programming stuff. I'm wondering if anyone knows a keyboard shortcut to switch between the text area and the bottom pane (shell, command prompt, or whatever they're calling it now). I've seen how-to for opening/closing panes and switching tabs, but starting to think switching between the bottom pane and the text area isn't doable.

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to go to bottom pane and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to go back.

Answer (score 0):

I do it pressing <kbd>F6</kbd>.  Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, like said by our friend, we just get to switch to the previous/next tab.